# Discord server auto-delete wehbook?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Before I start, I'm not just some kid who wants to hack a discord server of a friend for fun, I'm seriously looking for this.
I made a discord server with a friend and he told me he will give me Owner rank and I will make the server for him in return. So he gave it to me and I made all of the things that he wanted. I literally spent hours getting everything done and when I was done, he just removed my perms and banned me. Now, I added my bot on there (that gets admin when it joins) and he doesn't seem to realize that I can log in with this bot. I want to destroy the server and delete it, but since only the owner can do it, I want to delete all the channels, texts, roles, etc. Now, my bot is below all staff roles, but it has administrations, meaning that I can get anything I want on the server. I found out that people have done many interesting things with wehbooks, so I was wondering if I could make one delete all the channels. Is this possible?

Comment: The only thing you can do with discord webhooks is send messages into a channel, so you would not be able to do anything to his server.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what a webhook is. Webhooks function as an easy way to get automated messages and data updates sent to a text channel in your server. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send messages with discord webhooks. However, if your bot has perms to delete channels, you can use a website such as https://botclient-tk-20-.glitch.me/ to log in with your bot token. It allows you to delete channels and other things. I do not know this website very well though. It could very easily have a token stealer in it, so I would suggest resetting your bot token afterwards if you use this

EDIT: I feel like this site might be a bit better discordbotclient.jtmaveryk.repl.co

Comment: That first link seems a bit suspicious, with tons of grammar mistakes, and the other isn't much better.

Comment: @mjm0813 I try not to judge people for the quality of their English, it obviously isn't their first language and learning a new language is hard. I need 1 more rep in order to comment this on your post, but I will put it here instead. I feel like you should include instructions on how to log in with a bot token using lightcord if you are going to recommend it.

Comment: It's incredibly simple and I felt that it didn't need explaining. When you launch the client you see two prompts, one to login with username and password, and another to log in with token.

Comment: When I launched it, I was auto logged into my discord account. I looked around in the settings for a few minutes, couldn't find the option, and then I googled how to do it. No results from google either. That's when I had the idea of logging out of the discord account to see if the option was there

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a webhook for anything other than sending messages or sending files into a channel. You did mention that you had a bot with admin privileges, which could be used to do what you want via [Lightcord](https://lightcord.org), a custom discord client that lets you log in as a bot with the bot's token.